# ActionBarSherlock doesn't show anything on Android 2.3.3

Tags: android, cordova, actionbarsherlock

I set up ABS with a simple Android project and can't find out why no single part of the action bar shows up on 2.3.3 (left), but works perfectly on 4.0 (right: title, tabs and menu).

[image] [image]

What I did:

- Created new Android Project in Eclipse

  - Added `android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock"` in `<application>`
  - `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />`
  - Changed Java compliance to 1.6 (don't think this matters, should be the default anyway)
- Added ABS as library project (compiled against SDK version 15 as well)
- Did not add support library to my project (doesn't make a difference if I do)

Note: I have to use static attachment so I cannot extend one of the `Sherlock*` classes.

Source code:

```
package de.andidog.testthesherlock;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Log;

import com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock;
import com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.OnCreateOptionsMenuListener;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;

public class TestTheSherlockActivity extends Activity implements ActionBar.TabListener, OnCreateOptionsMenuListener
{
    protected ActionBarSherlock sherlock = ActionBarSherlock.wrap(this);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        sherlock.setUiOptions(ActivityInfo.UIOPTION_SPLIT_ACTION_BAR_WHEN_NARROW);

        showTabsNav();

        // TODO: check order of these statements
        sherlock.setContentView(R.layout.main);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    private void showTabsNav()
    {
        final ActionBar ab = sherlock.getActionBar();

        ab.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
            ab.addTab(ab.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setTabListener(this));

        ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        ab.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu)
    {
        return sherlock.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        menu.add("Refresh").setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_rotate).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
    {
        Log.d("TestTheSherlockActivity", "TAB RESELECTED");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft)
    {
        Log.d("TestTheSherlockActivity", "TAB CLICKED");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
    {
        Log.d("TestTheSherlockActivity", "TAB UNSELECTED");
    }
}
```

My `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.andidog.testthesherlock"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" >
        <activity
            android:name=".TestTheSherlockActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

How do I get this to work on 2.x?

Comment: Well... you can get it working by having your `Activity extend SherlockActivity` and implementing your code as if it were a normal activity (just using `getSupportActionBar` instead). Why can't you do this?

Comment: I want to get it working with PhoneGap, which forces you to use the `DroidGap` base class for activities. See my comment below on how I solved it in the end.

Comment: Ahhhh, sweet. Glad you got an answer from such a reputable source :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the second `setContentView` call, this is overwriting the layout inflated by ABS.

You should only be using the static attachment technique if you require extending from a non-Android base class. Otherwise it's much easier to extend from `SherlockActivity` (or any of the others).

Comment: That worked, nice. In fact I had a different problem – I'm trying to use PhoneGap with ABS, so that's why I can only use static attachment. Got it working by overriding all three `setContentView` signatures and calling `sherlock.setContentView` instead (without calling the super method). Thanks!! (I think I should put this in a tutorial...)

Comment: andidog - please do make a tutorial

Comment: @CI_Guy: [Android ActionBarSherlock plugin for tab bar](https://github.com/AndiDog/phonegap-android-actionbarsherlock-tabbar-plugin)